# Installing Android SDK Manager in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm now trying to install the SDK in Eclipse but it gives me the following Screen

[image]

Does anyone know why and how to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Run as administrator?

Comment: sorry, misunderstand you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close Eclipse and Explorer (probably the directory explorer) and click Yes.

Answer (score 0):

See if you have the folder `E:\..\Platform-tools` open in a window - generally corresponds to explorer.exe. I am not sure why it would give issue with eclipse.exe - you may want to try restarting eclipse :)